# Install XFCE after installing Raspbian without internet connection?

Tags: raspbian, apt

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B with a 16GB PNY class 4 SD card for memory that I received two days ago. I'm running Raspbian on NOOBS. After spending some time with it and interchanging operating systems to check which ones I wanted, Pidora's XFCE environment caught my eye. I was wondering if there was a way to install XFCE and replace LXDE with it on Raspbian using the package I've installed [here](http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.10/fat_tarballs/) rather than using

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

because I do not have a wireless adapter or usable ethernet connection to use.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to use the `dpkg` command, but beyond that I'm not sure. I will look into this and see if I can get an answer!

Comment: Yes, but the package comes in shell scripts instead of debian archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to compile XFCE from [source](http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.10/fat_tarballs/)?

If not, you could run `apt-get -s install xfce4` to simulate installing XFCE, which will print (among other things) a list of all packages that would be installed<sup>1</sup>:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acl alsa-base alsa-utils colord dbus-x11 desktop-base
  [...]
0 upgraded, 148 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

You can then download the necessary packages from the [Raspbian package repository](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/), copy them to a directory on your Raspberry and run `dpkg -i *.deb` to install them.

<sup>1: Your list will probably contain fewer packages, since you already have an X-server installed.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, however, I found a list of debian archives for xfce on packages.debian.org. Do you think those would work rather than sifting through the Raspbian package repo to find xfce?

Comment: Those should probably work too, just be sure to select the architecture `armhf`.

Comment: That was another question of mine, thanks.
I also have another one: If I have XFCE installed entirely later on, how could I remove LDXE and only use XFCE?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I might have got it wrong: according to [this article](http://www.memetic.org/raspbian-benchmarking-armel-vs-armhf/), the `armhf` packages are compiled for ARMv7 and up, so they won't run on the Rapsberry's ARMv6.

Comment: So, reading further in said article, it looks like you can either use Raspbian's `armhf` or Debian's `armel` packages and the Raspbian packages will give you (slightly) better performance.

Comment: As for your other question: It should be as easy as `apt-get remove lxde`, but I don't have a system to try that on right now.

Comment: To be safe, I'll use the package repo from Raspberry.

Comment: I'll test it out and get back to you on that.